# How to fix "key already in use" for Trackmania² Canyon?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing, trackmania-2

I bought Trackmania² Canyon via Steam. I think I was able to play regularly for some time (maybe a year ago).

I have then shared my Steam library with my son via the family library sharing and now it says

> Key registration failed. This game key is already used.

When I look into the list of games that are excluded from Family Library Sharing, Trackmania² is not listed, so I think I should be able to play it on up to 10 PCs.

[image: Screenshot: key registration failed]

[image: Screenshot: Family Library Sharing]

I have already tried:

- I copied the CD key from Steam and inserted it in Trackmania again. Still the same issue

What can I do to play Trackmania² on my PC again?

Comment: Where are you trying to enter the Key? In game or via Steam (activate a game/product)?

Comment: @Patta I entered it in the game